# How to add two objects to ObservableCollection only?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, observablecollection

SentBy has two items
SentTo has one item.
So I want to add the both objects to DirMessage.-> DirMessage will having three objects....

```
public ObservableCollection<DirectMessage> DirMessage { get; set; }
 ...........
DirMessage = new ObservableCollection<DirectMessage>();

var sentBy = await (.....   select index).ToListAsync();
var sentTo = await (....  select index).ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in sentBy)
{
    foreach(var item1 in sentTo)
    {
        DirMessage.Add(item1);
    }
    DirMessage.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: both sentBy and SentTo are of same type?

Comment: yes. It's same type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, if the are of same type,

```
var allTypes = sentBy.Concat(sentTo);
foreach(var item1 in allTypes)
{
  DirMessage.Add(item1);
}
```

Comment: @ThanhsharePoint I know its not you! btw did this help?